# Template code optimization for specific values of non-type parameters.

Tags: c++, templates, constants, boolean

```
template <bool flag>
class foo
{
    public:
        int bar()
        {
            if(flag)
            {
                // stuff
            }
        }
};
```

When the compiler compiles this class, it replaces the flag parameter by true or false. Then we have if(true) ( or if(false) ). Then, the if clause checks against a constant expression and WILL BE REMOVED at compile time. Can I expect compilers to behave like this?

Comment: why don't you provide a specialization for `false` which does nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizations are compiler-specific. Why don't you create release build and step through disassembly?

Still, this is not idiomatic way to do that. You should either use template specialization or method overloading. They both provide compile-time resolving. So, in this case I would prefer the latter:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <bool flag>
class foo
{
public:
    int bar()
    {
        _bar(std::integral_constant<bool, flag>())
    }
private:
    int _bar(std::true_type)
    {
        // stuff
    }
    int _bar(std::false_type)
    {
        // empty
    }
};
```

EDIT: this requires C++0x, but can be easily translated to C++98 by including `boost/type_traits` and changing `std::` directives to `boost::`. And, of course, it will require boost libraries.

Comment: This is C++0x. You should mention that, if the since the OP has not said that he is looking for a C++0x solution, and the question is not tagged C++0x.

Comment: Thank for pointing that out. I've just added comment that addresses this.

Comment: I have problems with that. Now I have two calls instead of one call. Isn't that much slower than the if clause?

Comment: Ah, good point. The `bar` should be defined as `inline` - it's a tip for compiler to "copy-pase" exact function code in place of its invocation. Once again we have to count on compiler to do the job, but in my opinion this solution is much more idiomatic. For example, STL or Boost both use this kind of compile-time resolution to a great success. Other solution that I have pointed out, e.g. class template specialization, would get rid of "extra" call, but it could lead to nasty code duplication and wired hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

No you can't. Any optimization is completely up to the compiler. Since you are using templates, you should write a specialization for both cases of `flag`.

Answer (score 2):

Expect, yes. Rely, no. But how would you notice anyway?

Note that you cannot instantiate the template with `false` if you write code inside the `if` statement which fails to compile when `flag` is `false`. Removing the test would be done by an optimizer, which conceptually runs after the compiler has figured out what the code means in the first place.