# If a function uses a template value-parameter, is it intelligently compiled?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose we create the following function:

```
template <int T>
void test_function()
{
    if (T == 0) {

    }
}
```

Now let's use `test_function<1>()`. Is there a standard behavior for its compilation? Will compilers interpret `test_function` as an empty function, or will the comparison `1 == 0` always be made at run-time?

Comment: Uh, this doesn't look like valid C++...

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I've edited my question and successfully compiled it -- as I should have done the first time.

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174764/template-code-optimization-for-specific-values-of-non-type-parameters?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030497/c-use-templates-to-avoid-compiler-from-checking-a-boolean) and many others like [this also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970532/what-do-compilers-do-with-compile-time-branching)

Comment: Compiler could be able to optimize that.

Comment: This was a difficult question to search, these are indeed duplicates. I would be comfortable with closing this question.